# Java replace a string with certain characters to hide the string?

Tags: java, string, character, replace

Ok so I want to replace a string which is returned by a user with specific input. I want to replace every lower case letter, but not spaces!, in the string with a '?'. The place where the inserted '?' should go is in the print statement with the random space (" ") at the end. Thanks for the help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program05 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 

    {
    Scanner scanner01 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputPhrase; 


        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a common phrase to begin!: ");
            inputPhrase = scanner01.nextLine(); 

        }  while (!inputPhrase.matches("[a-z ]+"));

        System.out.print("Press [ENTER] to continue...");  
            try  
            {  
              System.in.read();  
              System.in.skip(System.in.available()); 
            } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();} //though that was a neat little touch 


         do {

            boolean valid = true;


            for (int i = 0; i < inputPhrase.length(); i++)
                {

                 System.out.println("Common Phrase\n-------------" + "\n" + " " );  


                    }






            //System.out.print(inputPhrase);



         } while (!inputPhrase.matches("[a-z ]+"));

    }

}
```

Comment: AFAIK this is impossible using `Scanner` or a simple reader. From Java 6, you can use [`Console#readPassword`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword()) that will allow what you want/need.

Comment: Don't catch `Exception`! Catch the actual exception type, and if you really don't want to handle it, wrap it in a `RuntimeException` and rethrow it instead of printing the stack trace. You'll save yourself some debugging headaches later.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) in conjunction with the regular expression `\p{Lower}`:

```
String str = "Hello World";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\p{Lower}", "?"));
```

```
H???? W????
```

Comment: Then how we can get original text back

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your String in variable s. Then you can go letter by letter in a loop with

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
}
```

So what this comes down to is checking if char c is lowercase, and acting accordingly. One possible way to determine if char c is lowercase is to check its int value and see if its between 97 and 122 inclusive.

```
int intValue = (int) c;
if (intValue >= 97 && intValue <= 122) { }
```

If it is, then replace it with a question mark.

A simple way to do it would be to create a temp String, and as you loop through your source string, add every letter until you get to lowercase leters, in which case you add a question mark until you're done.

Comment: Oh, but my code only allows for lower case characters to be entered into the string. so if anything else is entered it reprompts. Sorry i didnt clarify that.

Comment: !inputPhrase.matches("[a-z ]+") <<<< that line only allows for lower case

Comment: I'm afraid I may have misunderstood you. Can you give a few examples of what the String replacement should achieve? For example, for input "xyz" what about would you want, and so on? I don't think my answer above applies to what you're actually trying to do. You can edit your original question too add this new information in if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply make use of the regular expression functionality built into the API, for example...

```
String question = "This is a Test String".replaceAll("([a-z])", "?");
System.out.println(question);
```

Would output...

```
T??? ?? ? T??? S?????
```

nb `[a-z]` gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

In most of the scenarios we want to hide our personal details like phone number, email etc. Here I am assuming that you want to hide characters in an email or phone number.

Let's say  `CredentialModel` is a class which looks like:

```
public class CredentialModel {
    private String username;
    private String phoneno;
    private String email;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPhoneno() {
        return phoneno;
    }
    public void setPhoneno(String phoneno) {
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CredentialModel [username=" + username + ", phoneno=" + phoneno + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }
}
```

and encryption method be like:

```
public CredentialModel encryptPrivateDetails(CredentialModel credentialModel) {
    String phoneno = credentialModel.getPhoneno();
    String email = credentialModel.getEmail().split("\\@")[0];
    String domain = credentialModel.getEmail().split("\\@")[1];
    if (phoneno != null) {
        int minlength = 9;
        int blocklength = 5;
        if (phoneno.length() > blocklength) {
            if (phoneno.length() > minlength) {
                int visibleStartLength = 3;
                credentialModel.setPhoneno(phoneno.substring(0, visibleStartLength)
                        + String.format("%" + blocklength + "s", "").replace(' ', 'x')
                        + phoneno.substring(visibleStartLength + blocklength));
            } else
                credentialModel.setPhoneno(String.format("%" + blocklength + "s", "").replace(' ', 'x')
                        + phoneno.substring(blocklength));
        }
    }
    if (email != null) {
        int minlength = 2;
        if (email.length() > minlength)
            credentialModel.setEmail(email.substring(0, minlength)
                    + String.format("%" + (email.length() - minlength + 1) + "s", "@").replace(' ', 'x') + domain);
        else
            credentialModel.setEmail(String.format("%" + (email.length() + 1) + "s", "@").replace(' ', 'x') + domain);
    }
    return credentialModel;
}
```

Please adjust as per your requirement.